# ¿Cómo hacer que sed reemplace datos en un archivo con lo que llegue de un pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, pipe

¡Hola!

Estoy intentando implementar un proceso que, a través de un bash script, genere un valor aleatorio y lo use para reemplazar valores existentes en un archivo.

El archivo no es muy grande, pero nadie debe tener que hacer esto a mano todos los días. El contenido del archivo es algo como

```
header:2022-01-01:v1.0
random:a1b2c3
```

Sé que para hacer el reemplazo que quiero, cambiando lo que está en la línea de `random` después del dos-puntos `:` y puedo usar sed, digamos que con

`sed -i 's|random:a1b2c3|random:98765' archivo.csv`

E incluso, podría correrlo infinitas veces reemplazando siempre la cadena después de `random:` por otra cosa

`sed -i "s|random:.\+|random:98765|" archivo.csv`

Por otra parte, [he encontrado](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230673/130378) que es posible generar una cadena aleatoria (no me interesa que sea criptográficamente fuerte o algo así) usando un comando como este (que jala /dev/urandom y produce algo de la longitud que desee a través de `head`:

`head /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 | head -c10`

Pero no sé cómo entregarle ese valor a `sed` para que lo use como el valor para poner en el reemplazo, digamos que usando un pipe `|` para conectar los procesos. Algo como esto (aunque sé que esto no funciona y tampoco veo en la documentación cómo lograrlo):

`head /dev/urandom blablablá | sed -i 's|random:.\+|random:$1' archivo.csv`

Donde el $1 representa lo que llega por el pipe.

Eventualmente esperaría poder correr esto periódicamente, pero sin automatizar el reemplazo, es difícil llegar a definir el cronjob.

¿Cómo podría lograr esto en un bash shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Después de darle vueltas, el camino parece ser no intentar hacer el proceso tan rápido. Posiblemente podría hacerse en awk, pero logré hacerlo con sed preparando variables en el shell script.

Puedo configurar la longitud del valor, el dominio y el archivo a usar. Podría incluso entregar esto como argumentos xargs (peeero no me servía para como quiero configurar la ejecución). Llegué a ésto:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable para la longitud del valor aleatorio
length=10
#Variable para el regexp que define el dominio del valor aleatorio
validChars="A-Za-z0-9"
#Archivo donde modifico algo por el aleatorio
listFile="archivo.csv"

randomValue=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc $validChars | head -c$length)
sed -i "s|random:.\+|random:$randomValue|" $listFile
echo $randomValue " was put into file " $listFile
exit 0;
```

Para asegurarme de que el cronjob sepa dónde encontrar todo, es sano mover la ejecución al directorio donde está el shell script (y el CSV)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable para la longitud del valor aleatorio
length=10
#Variable para el regexp que define el dominio del valor aleatorio
validChars="A-Za-z0-9"
#Archivo donde modifico algo por el aleatorio
listFile="archivo.csv"

# Asegurarse de que se buscan las cosas en el directorio que esperamos!
cd /home/user/cronjobs/

randomValue=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc $validChars | head -c$length)
sed -i "s|random:.\+|random:$randomValue|" $listFile
echo $randomValue " was put into file " $listFile
exit 0;
```

En este estado, puedo crear un symlink (con `ln`) en `/etc/cron.daily` para este shell script (dándole los permisos de ejecución correctos) y va a correr cada día. Hay otras carpetas comodín para cron.hourly, cron.monthly...

`$ sudo ln -s /home/user/cronjobs/randomFileRefresh /etc/cron.daily/randomFileRefresh`

y asegurandome que este script no tenga extensión en el nombre (o si no, el cronjob no corre). Uno puede probar si el OS lo va a ejecutar con `run-parts` así:

```
$ sudo run-parts --list /etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/0anacron
/etc/cron.daily/randomFileRefresh
```

Comment: He estado tratando de construir variantes, pero creo ninguna ha sido tan precisa como la que haz publicado.
Tengo la sospecha que Perl tiene algo aún más eficiente.

Comment: @Cuauhtli Perl siempre podrá hacerlo más eficiente. Hasta acá me dio el cerebro y la paciencia del cliente :P